# Property 'SVGResize' | 'onresize' does not exist on type 'SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

React + SVG.

I need to handle the event of `svg` element resizing. I see it has the [SVGResize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/SVGResize) and [onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Events) events. I try to use each of them but I get the compilation error for each case:

```
const msg1 = (e: any) => console.log(`Message 1: SVG resized.`);
const msg2 = (e: any) => console.log(`Message 2: SVG resized.`);
```

Now I try to use my functions:

```
return (<svg id={this.paperId} height={height} version="1.1" 
width={width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="paper" 
SVGResize={msg1}> </svg>);
```

Compilation error:

> Property 'SVGResize' does not exist on type 'SVGProps'.

```
return (<svg id={this.paperId} height={height} version="1.1" 
width={width} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="paper" 
onresize={msg2}> </svg>);
```

Compilation error:

> Property 'onresize' does not exist on type 'SVGProps'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onresize` event is a property of global event handlers. It is the same as `window.onresize` and does nothing on the element level.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

If you want to redraw the SVGs based on the window size you should listen for the `window.onresize` event and redraw based on that.

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe on `svg` element size changing?

Comment: By subscribe I guess you mean add the onresize attribute to the svg element? No, onresize on an element will be ignored. It's probably the best to let CSS handle the redrawing of your SVGs using media queries.

Comment: I draw diagram on `svg`. I need that `svg` element will be resized each time when window will be resized and its (svg) content will be redrawn too. I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Use the viewBox attribute! Let's say the max values of your diagram are 500 for width and height, then you can give your SVG a viewBox="0 0 500 500". Put your SVG in a container div. Then give your SVG a width and height of 100%. The contents of your SVG will be scaled according to the viewBox. The size of your SVG will always be the size of your div.